# send_mail works locally but not on production hosting

Tags: django, digital-ocean, smtplib, django-mailer

The following works locally but as I deployed it to production hosting at Digital Ocean, the email is not sending as I test on shell command (python manage.py shell) like below. The send_mail line just got stuck there and am getting error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable after few minutes. How can I capture the error on the email sending? Please advise how can I troubleshoot this issue.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('test email', 'hello world', 'xxxx@gmail.com', ['xxxx@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False)

# Email settings
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxx' #my gmail password
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@gmail.com' #my gmail username
EMAIL_PORT = 587
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: It turns out Digital Ocean blocked my app's SMTP. Once they unblocked after I submitted a support ticket, it starts working. There wasn't any blocking on other app in the same hosting tho

Answer (score 1):

Your Django app settings look correct but you should also head over to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and make sure you enable access to lower security applications.
Also consider [creating an application-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en&ctx=ch_DisplayUnlockCaptcha)  if you're using Two-Factor-Authentication.